# Async Await and how to avoid await Task.Delay

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await

I am trying to retrieve 100 pages from an Url. 
The Url is formatted like this:
https://www.someBlogSite.com/thread.php?t=xxxx&page=

So my for loop basically iterates through these pages and stores the result in a html file on my local disk.

https://www.someBlogSite.com/thread.php?t=xxxx&page=1
https://www.someBlogSite.com/thread.php?t=xxxx&page=2
.
.
https://www.someBlogSite.com/thread.php?t=xxxx&page=99

This is my working code, **is there a way to avoid using await Task.Delay(10000)?** The reason I have to use it is because otherwise my code exits before all the 100 page contents have been retrieved.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace RetrieveImages
{

    public class PerformingGet

    {
        static void Main(string[] args) => MainAsync(args).Wait();

        static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
        {
            //Instantiating HttpClient once in the main method since this is costly
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Base Url--going forward only this will need to be edited per collection
            string pageBaseUrl = "https://www.someBlogSite.com/thread.php?t=xxxx&page=";
            var collectionOfUrls= new List<string>();

            for (int pageNum = 1; pageNum < 100; pageNum++)
            {
                string pageUrl = pageBaseUrl + pageNum;
                collectionOfUrls.Add(pageUrl);

            }

            var tasks = collectionOfUrls.Select(url => GetRequestString(client, url));

            var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            var text = string.Join("\r\n", results);
            WriteTextAsync(text);

            foreach (var x in collectionOfUrls)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                //await GetRequest(client, x);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Task completed");
            await Task.Delay(10000);
        }


        async static Task<string> GetRequestString(HttpClient client, string Url)
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(Url))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        return await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }


                return string.Empty;
            }
        }


        static async void WriteTextAsync(string text)
        {
            // Set a variable to the My Documents path.
            string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            // Write the text asynchronously to a new file named "WriteTextAsync.txt".
            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(mydocpath, "WriteTextAsync.html")))
            {
                await outputFile.WriteAsync(text);
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `async void`.

Comment: ... ^^ so you're not awaiting `WriteTextAsync`

Comment: You mean do this:
await WriteTextAsync(text);

And how should WriteTextAsync be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use async void (unless you really know what you are doing, or Visual Studio generated one for you, e.g. an event handler). If you need to return nothing from an `async` method, have it return a `Task` (with no generic type parameter at all). Your code doesn't actually have to return it; the compiler does that for you.

```
static async Task WriteTextAsync(string text)
{
    string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(mydocpath, "WriteTextAsync.html")))
    {
        await outputFile.WriteAsync(text);
    }
    //Notice no return statement
}
```

This will allow you to await it, even though it doesn't return a value.

```
await WriteTextAsync(text);
```

If you await the task, you shouldn't need the `Task.Delay()` call at the end.